# Regex x(?!n) with optional characters in the x selector

Tags: javascript, regex, option-type

So I have a javascript program that solves for 1 variable.  I'm coming to a roadblock when selecting numbers that DON'T have a variable associated with them.

Here is my current regex expression:

`(\+|-)?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?(?![a-z])`

takes input like `15000.53=1254b+21`
and returns `[15000.53, 125, +21]`, when it should return `[15000.53, +21]` (yes, the + is supposed to be there)

I know why it is happening.  The number of digits is optional so the function can handle large numbers and floats, but they are optional, so it is hard to make sure the entire number is selected.  The result of this is selecting all the digits of the number EXCEPT the one directly next to the variable.

Anyone know of a way for the number of digits to stay optional, yet still make sure a variable doesn't follow the number?  Thanks!

```
var reg = (\+|-)?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?(?![a-z]);
var numbers = [];
var equation = '15000.53=1254b+21';
while (aloneInt = reg.exec(side[0])) {
    numbers.push(aloneInt[0]);
}
```

Comment: Why isn't `1254` in the expected output ?

Comment: When I match that string to that regex, I don't get what you say you get, I get `["15000.53", undefined, "15000", ".53"]`

Comment: `([0-9]+)` currently means that the number of digits is optional, which it should be.  This means it only selects the digits that don't have a variable after them, and then returns that number.  It would skip over `4b` because 4 is only one digit. `41b` would return 4.  I don't want it to return 1254, because that is just multiplying the variable, and I want to get all of the constants.

Comment: sorry, should have put that I'm looping through with a while loop, adding that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following expression:

```
(?![+-]?[0-9.]+[a-z])(\+|-)?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?
```

The added negative lookahead `(?![+-]?[0-9.]+[a-z])` makes sure there isn't one or more optionally signed floating point numbers that are followed by a letter from the alphabet.

In other words, it makes sure there isn't a number followed by a variable name, then it matches the number.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tF3sD4)

Comment: @m.buettner I wrote the answer quickly and left for a while so I didn't have time to write the explanation but I will add it right now. On the other hand, Regex101 does support the Javascript flavor, just check above the regex entry box and you will see a list of languages supported. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, wow, that must be new. Good to know that I can finally replace regexpal for JS-related questions! Thanks :)